# install Xcode 8.3.3 beside Xcode 10.2.1 in macOS mojave

Tags: xcode8, macos-mojave

I have installed Xcode 8.3.3 that I need for an old project with swift 3.3
and when I try to lunch Xcode 8.3.3 I have this error message

```
Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode 8.app/Contents/MacOS/../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode 8.app/Contents/MacOS/../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
```

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 8.3.3 is no more support in MacOS Mojave 10.14+